# Please tell me why does this object iterator just allows logging one time

Tags: javascript, object, iterator, console.log

```js
let str = '<span class="my"> <var suv="inn">';

let regexp = /<(([a-z]+)\s*([^>]*))>/g;

let result = str.matchAll(regexp);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result);
//It is an iterable object'
 
console.log("Array from method");
var a = Array.from(result);
console.log(a[0]);
console.log(a[1]);

console.log("for loop method");
for (let value of result){
console.log(value);
}
```

we can see that when we place the ArrayFrom method first, it logged the values but ForLoop method didn't.

```js
let str = '<span class="my"> <var suv="inn">';

let regexp = /<(([a-z]+)\s*([^>]*))>/g;

let result = str.matchAll(regexp);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result);
//It is an iterable object'

console.log("for loop method");
for (let value of result){
console.log(value);
}

console.log("Array from method");
var a = Array.from(result);
console.log(a[0]);
console.log(a[1]);
```

and similarly when we place the ForLoop method first, it logged the values but ArraFrom method didn't.

**Why is not both methods logging after one method logs.**
(I really didn't know how else to frame my question, I really hope I'm clear!)

Comment: _“`/<(([a-z]+)\s*([^>]*))>/g`”_ — HTML is not a regular language. Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job. [Have you tried using an HTML parser instead?](/a/1732454/4642212) Use [DOMParser](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser): `new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");`.

Comment: If HTML is problem, I tried to replace < by 1 and > by 2 everywhere it becomes `let str = '1span class="my"2 1var suv="inn"2';` `let regexp = /1(([a-z]+)\s*([^2]*))2/g;` the output is still the same, or maybe I didn't understand it?

Comment: That's not going to make html regular.

Comment: Charles and Sebastian are correct but it is immaterial to Aashit's problem as I've discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to be happening is that after each progression through the iterator, the current item is being removed from the faux array, leaving the iterator empty.

If you stick `console.log(Array.from(result).length)` before the `for...of` loop, the `length` will be `2` and the faux array will be emptied by `Array.from()` so the `for...of` loop returns nothing. If you put `console.log(Array.from(result).length)` twice in a row, the result will be `2` then `0`.

If you don't call an `Array.from(result).length` before, but you stick it just once after `for...of` the `length` will also be `0` because it was emptied by the `for...of`.

[This is expected behavior.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/o50ids/is_an_iterator_object_supposed_to_automatically/h2k7g8e/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: So all iterators in JavaScript gets emptied  after each progression through iterator or is it just `[object RegExp String Iterator]`?

Comment: "Nothing in the docs on Mozilla says it's supposed to do this." The [article for `.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#return_value) says that the iterable is not restartable.

Comment: Just got [a very thorough explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/o50ids/is_an_iterator_object_supposed_to_automatically/h2k7g8e/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit

Comment: @Corey Thanks, I missed that somehow.